# Не коннектится база данных MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Поставил сайт на хостинг hostinger.ru.
Закинул сайт через FTP.
Создал базу данных.
Пытаюсь её приконнектить таким кодом:

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","u141735831_ardb","********");
mysql_select_db("u141735831_db",$db);
?>
```

На что мне отвечает ошибкой

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'u141735831_ardb'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/u141735831/public_html/blocks/bd.php on line 2
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка указывает, что

1. Пользователь этот доступа к базе не имеет
2. Либо пароль неверный

Поддерживаю [[@Vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd)](/users/4996/vfvtnjd), посмотрите и то и другое через phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

У вас доступа нет к БД серверу. Чтобы открыть доступ нужно через `phpmyadmin` в вкладке `Priveliegies` добавить пользователя

`u141735831_ardb@localhost`
к вашему бд  `u141735831_ardb`

Comment: u141735831_ardb - это и есть пользователь.
u141735831_db - а вот это и есть бд.
В phpmyadmin нет привилегий. Ну по крайней мере у этого хостинга.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/6314/lgunchik, сорри, попутал название  бд и пользователя.